AudioKit with Recording and Pitch tap Concurrenlty?
Can AudioKit be setup to both record from the microphone and install a pitch tap on it at the same time?
Every attempt I make gets error 'uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap() when the recording is started. Either real device or simulator. It fails in both cases.
func startRecordingMicWithTapHandler(tapHandler:TapHandlerProtocol, recordAudio:Bool) {
    ///It appears that we cannot both record the mic and install a tap on it at the same time
    ///Error is reason: 'required condition is false: nullptr == Tap()' when the record starts.
    checkMicPermission(completion: {granted in
        if !granted {
            Logger.shared.reportError(self, "No microphone permission")
        }
    })
    setSession()
    
    ///Based on CookBook Tuner
    self.engine = AudioEngine()
    guard let engine = self.engine else {
        Logger.shared.reportError(self, "No engine")
        return
    }
    guard let input = engine.input else {
        Logger.shared.reportError(self, "No input")
        return
    }
    if recordAudio {
        do {
            self.recorder = try NodeRecorder(node: input)
        } catch let err {
            Logger.shared.reportError(self, "Recorder \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    else {
        self.recorder = nil
    }
    guard let device = engine.inputDevice else {
        Logger.shared.reportError(self, "No input device")
        return
    }

    self.initialDevice = device
    self.mic = input
    self.tappableNodeA = Fader(mic!)
    self.tappableNodeB = Fader(tappableNodeA!)
    self.tappableNodeC = Fader(tappableNodeB!)
    self.silence = Fader(tappableNodeC!, gain: 0)
    engine.output = silence

//        self.pitchTap = PitchTap(mic!) { pitch, amp in
//            DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                print("============>>", pitch, amp)
//            }
//        }
    self.pitchTap = installTapHandler(node: mic!,
                      bufferSize: 4096,
                      tapHandler: tapHandler,
                      asynch: true)
    self.tapHandler = tapHandler
    if let pitchTap = self.pitchTap {
        pitchTap.start()
    }
    
    do {
        ///As per the order in Cookbook Recorder example
        try engine.start()
        if recordAudio {
            try recorder?.record() <===========  Error OCCURS HERE
        }
    }
    catch {
        Logger.shared.reportError(self, "Error starting engine: \(error)")
    }
}

